# Preparing a transaction with many outpts

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning, cli

What would be the exact command to prepare a transaction with multiple outputs, to a specific address?

I'm able to list all my outputs with `lightning-cli listfunds`, but I'm not sure how to include them all in a transaction with `txprepare`, so I can submit the transaction later.

If possible I would also like to set the fee as low as possible, i.e. 1 sat/b or lower.

Comment: Am I understanding right that you want to use multiple UTXOs in inputs and send to a single output?

Comment: That's exactly right. The help of lightning-cli suggests `txprepare outputs [feerate] [minconf] [utxos]` but I'm not completely sure how to specify several outputs. Also, the feerate will be per b or kw?